# SQL Bulk Upload

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

Is there a way to bulk upload data into a SQL table without using the INSERT function for each row?  I'm using mySQL.

I currently have a program that constaly pulls live data off the internet, and stores in a database.  When doing this, it erases a table and then puts the new data in.  When it does this though, it does it a row at a time.   This would be ok, execpt that other programs pull that data at asyncronous times, and as such there is not guarantee that it picks up the complete table.  Sometimes it will pull 10 rows, 20, etc.   If there is a way I could insert all rows at once, such that other programs will pull 0 (just after the table is erased) or all rows that would be awesome.

Thanks, and any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: How many rows are you typically inserting at a time here?

Comment: about 50... not a whole lot but enough where those timing differences are definitely present

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql table type is InnoDB just use a transaction. Then all the updates will be visible at the same time when you commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to quickly load the table from a file.

If you are concerned about clients getting a partial view of the data, the easiest way to avoid that would be to do your load into a temp table, then do some [table renaming](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) to make the change appear to be instantaneous.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines as well, the temp table approach that is.  I should have also mentioned that the program that is pushing the data into the database is a C# program..

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Eric's alternate solution: An other way to do it, instead of a temp table is to have effective dates. The SQL to access the table would change such that it would select the most recent date for the pieces of data. If it's half-way through an update, the select should grab half new data and half old data. Once the new data has arrived, you can feel free to delete the old data.